# use IFNULL in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have a query in `laravel` which is working fine.

```
$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
        ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
        ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  'downloads.is_download' )
        ->orderBy('subjectID')
        ->get();
```

There is only one issue that `is_download` comes null when there is no relative entry in table. After some research I found that there is a function `IFNULL` by using which I can change `is_download` `null` to `0`. So here is my query which is not working. Blank screen is showing.

```
$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
        ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
        ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 ) )
        ->orderBy('subjectID')
        ->get();
```

I am able to write this query in my phpmyadmin but not know how to write in `laravel`

This is the api, So whole code looks like

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression as raw;
use project\Models\Subject;
use project\Models\Semester;
use project\Models\StudentRegistration;

$app->get('/api/getSubject/:studentID', function($studentID) use ($app) {
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $currentUser = StudentRegistration::where('studentID', $studentID)->first();

$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
        ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
        ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 ) )
        ->orderBy('subjectID')
        ->get();
print_r($subjects);
    return $app->response->write(json_encode([
                'error' => 0,
                'subjects' => $subjects
    ]));
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Try like this:

```
DB::Raw('IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 )');


$subjects = $app->db->table('subjects')->LeftJoin('downloads', 'subjects.subjectID', '=', 'downloads.subject_id')
    ->where('universityID', $currentUser->universityID)->where('semesterID', $currentUser->semesterID)->where('courseID', $currentUser->courseID)
    ->select('subjects.subjectID', 'subjects.subjectName', 'subjects.price',  DB::Raw('IFNULL( `downloads`.`is_download` , 0 )') )
    ->orderBy('subjectID')
    ->get();
```

Comment: blank screen. no change.

Comment: Did you use \DB::table() instead of $app->db->table() and \DB::Raw() ? This should work fine. Otherwise check your query again when you are using it in laravel.

Comment: In laravel documentation, I didn't see anything like this. So, it's better to use DB::table().

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use like this way,

```
DB::raw('IFNULL( downloads.is_download, 0) as is_download')
```

Comment: this has helped me in my case thanks i had  a scenario that required this case another other selections  for example $colArray = [ 'column1' , 'otherColumn' ,DB::raw('IFNULL( downloads.is_download, 0) as is_download') ];

Answer (score 0):

This my code

```
->whereRaw('customer_id = IFNULL(?, customer_id)', [$request->customer_id])
```