# how to change null value to zero

Tags: php, laravel, join, null, left-join

values of columns that is empty returns null. How to I make turn the null to zero so that if the value is null it returns zero.

```
 public function getThumbsUpAttribute($value){
     return $value !== null ? $value : 0;
}


public function videos()
{


        // return VideoViewsLikes::all();
       $rec_videos = Videos::orderBy('videos.created_at', 'DESC')->where('videos.publish', 1)
            ->leftJoin('video_views_likes', 'videos.vid_id', '=', 'video_views_likes.vid_id')
            ->select('videos.vid_id', 'videos.title as title', DB::raw("sum(video_views_likes.thumbs_down)  as dislike"), DB::raw("sum(video_views_likes.views)  as views"), DB::raw("sum(video_views_likes.thumbs_up)  as likes"))
            ->groupby('videos.vid_id')
            ->groupby('videos.title')
                ->get();
      
         return response()->json(['success' => $rec_videos]);
}
```

it still returns null.

Comment: Have you tried this? I assume it's the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153019/use-ifnull-in-laravel/36153280

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
 DB::raw("sum(video_views_likes.thumbs_down)  as dislike");
```

you can use [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) witch Return the first non-null value

```
 DB::raw(" COALESCE(sum(video_views_likes.thumbs_down),0)  as dislike");
```